# ASP.NET API Gateway strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, .net, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using ASP.NET Microservices plus a separate Ocelot API Gateway which serves for authentication/ authorization and rerouting.
This is my config file:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    // *** User API ***   
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get"],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/{id}",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod":  "Get",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      },
      "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
        "Administrator": "true"
      }
    },

    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Put" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/{id}",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Put",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      },
      "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
        "Administrator": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Delete" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/{id}",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Delete",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      },
      "RouteClaimsRequirement": {
        "Administrator": "true"
      }
    },

    //edit,get logged user
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/LoggedUser",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Put" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/LoggedUser",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Put",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      }
    },

    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/LoggedUser",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/LoggedUser",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Get",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      }
    }
    //edit,get logged user
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7193"
  }
}
```

Now here is the problem.
I have the endpoint [GET] /User/LoggedUser (at the bottom) and it is configured **without any authorization** and it calls /api/User/LoggedUser.
I also have the endpoint [GET] /User/{id} and it is configured **WITH authorization** and it calls /api/User/{id}

If I use the current configuration as a whole and try calling [GET] /User/LoggedUser with authenticated user, but without the claim Administrator : true -> ** it does not work**

If **I delete** the rerouting for [GET] /User/{id}, which as you can see, is a totally separate endpoint rerouting - the above problem disappears.
It is as if Ocelot treats these 2 endpoints as one. But I do not understand why.
And here is the console log:
[image]

The problem is only with these 2 endpoints. If I call [PUT] /User/LoggedUser it does not work until I delete [PUT] /User/{id} .No other problems were detected. At least for now.

**Update 1**

So I renamed my API endpoints from /api/User/LoggedUser to be /LoggedUser (downstream path), changed my upstream path to /Test/LoggedUser and it worked.
So, clearly it is an url conflict. How should I handle such problem?

**Update 2**

Again, I changed the endpoints to the following:

```
 {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Get/LoggedUser",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/Get/LoggedUser",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Get",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      }
    },

    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Edit/LoggedUser",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Put" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/Edit/LoggedUser",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Put",
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "Cart.API",
          "Catalogue.API",
          "Identity.API",
          "offline_access"
        ]
      }
    }
```

And still, there is  conflict.

**Update 3**

I have other endpoints which are overlapping to some extend. For example:

```
{
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/Login",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/Login",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Post"
    },
{
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/User/Register",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Post" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7268
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/Register",
      "DownstreamHttpMethod": "Post"
    }
```

Yet, no problem with these endpoints. They are both POST, they both start with api/User and /User. I do not see what is the problem with the other endpoints.

Comment: As you describe it, there seams to be a conflict between the routes:  `"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/{id}"`, and `"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/User/LoggedUser"`. If you think about it the first route matches the second route as well since the string template {id} matches the string "LoggedUser". Can you reverse the order of the routes or rename one of the url's to exclude this possible scenario ?

Comment: I agree that there is a conflict. I found a way for it to work. Please, check my updated post for more info.

Comment: `/api/User/Login` does not overlap with `/api/User/Register`. It would have overlapped if you used a parameter (a value inside brackets) like `/api/User/{any_string_here}`

Comment: Yes, but if you check my Update 2 code they are totally different routes and still not working.

Comment: The whole problem is the Authorization part within Ocelot, IMO. Because If I use both re-routed endpoints from my original configuration with a token which includes the proper claim both endpoints work and give proper results. But for some reason the authorization rules from the one reroute goes to the other without (clear) explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem should be fixed from the routing configuration of the backend api, rather than the ocelot configuration. You should configure the default routes order (precedence) from specific to generic. In the above case `/api/User/LoggedUser` should be matched before `/api/User/{id}`. Take a look at [this](https://rion.io/2015/11/13/understanding-routing-precedence-in-asp-net-mvc/) article for some more info about routing precedence in asp.net mvc and web.api.

Comment: I agree that there is an actual problem. But just a question: why this problem arises now? I 've been using this api for 2 months, with frontend, postman, swagger as well. No problem whatsoever.